# Issue Installing Packages With R

Tags: r

I am getting this error trying to install `ISwR` in the console:

```
install.packages("ISwR")

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/contrib/4.3/ISwR_2.0-8.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 212970 bytes (207 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 207 KB

sh: tar: command not found
Warning in install.packages :
  error in running command
Warning in install.packages :
  'tar' returned non-zero exit code 127
Error in install.packages : file ‘/var/folders/hv/x42p9t310sxdm0dprm6qfmh40000gn/T//RtmpejYG9G/downloaded_packages/ISwR_2.0-8.tgz’ is not a macOS binary package
```

I recently was required to alter my PATH for a MySQL course and I believe that might have something to do with it. This is my current PATH:

${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Running "Sys.getenv" returns:

"${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/aaronmccullough/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/postback"

Comment: As suggested by @ThomasBeck, please run `Sys.getenv("PATH")` and edit your question to include it that information

Answer (score 0):

You can check what R detects the current path is

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

If its missing /usr/bin it may help to change your Path locally/ in the R environment to include this.

Otherwise it may be worth downloading the files from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISwR/index.html)  and then installing locally

```
install.packages("ISwR", repos = NULL, type="binary")
```

Comment: I don't think downloading and installing locally will help - presumably you need `tar` to unpack the `.tgz` binary one way or the other??

Comment: Running Sys.getenv returns:

"${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/aaronmccullough/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/postback"